# Using YAML pipelines with SVN on Azure DevOps

Tags: svn, azure-devops

We have several codebases in SVN repositories that we'd like to add CI/CD to using Azure DevOps. Ideally I'd like to use the YAML-based pipelines rather than the classic visual designer; but according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/?view=azure-devops#supported-repository-types), YAML is only supported for Git repositories on Azure Repos, BitBucket Cloud, GitHub or GitHub Enterprise Server.

Is there any way around this limitation, e.g. through the REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way around this limitation, e.g. through the REST API?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such a way around this limitation at this moment.

Just as you know, the YAML only support the repository of **git** type, and MS haven't expand the feature and YAML grammer to support the YAML for `TFVC` or `SVN` repository.

You can also check the document [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#type):

[image]

Besides, both `SVN` and `TFVC` are centralized code management methods. Currently YAML does not even support `TFVC`, so there should be a long way to support SVN. There are many users have the demand with TFVS: [Make YAML support TFVC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/635044/make-yaml-support-tfvc.html). You could also add your request for SVN on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Since only one workaround is migrate your repository from SVN to Git, but I could not sure whether it is feasible for you to do migrate. You could check the document [Learn how to migrate from Subversion (SVN) to Git, including history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/perform-migration-from-svn-to-git?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that might have been the case. I'll add a request to the UserVoice site.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, I've added the request to the UserVoice site here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/823415/add-yaml-pipelines-support-for-svn.html